# Javascript/Typescript: Check if Combination of cost and value exists

Tags: javascript, typescript

If i have a list of choices that each have a cost and a value,
how can i check if a combination of choices exists, where a given value is exactly met, but a max cost is not overceeded?

Here is an example:

```js
const VAL      = 10;
const MAX_COST = 19;

let choices = [
    [{cost: 10, val: 3}, {cost:8, val: 2}, {cost: 6, val:  1}], // From every line, only one can be chosen
    [{cost: 10, val: 3}, {cost:4, val: 3}, {cost: 6, val:  3}],
    [{cost: 7, val: 5}, {cost:4, val: 3}, {cost: 11, val:  3}],
    [{cost:4, val: 3}, {cost: 11, val:  3}, {cost: 1, val: 1},],
];
```

In this example the anwser would be yes, because `{cost: 10, val: 3}, {cost:4, val: 3}, {cost:4, val: 3},  {cost: 1, val: 1}` can be chosen, adding up to a total cost of 19 and having a combined value of **exactly 10**.

In the real usecase there will be up to 3000 choices that have to be made, so bruteforcing is not viable.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: How would you think this could be done without brute force?

Comment: Bruteforcing was the best way i could come up with. That is why i asked on here, if there is a better method.

Comment: When do you want to perform this check? At compile/transpile time using typescript or at runtime? Are the choices always defined in the source code?

Comment: The choices are not defined in the source code, so this has to be calculated at runtime

Comment: Did you try running your script with 3000 entries? I don't think it will be that slow

Answer (score 0):

Processing 3000 entries isn't a lot of work for JavaScript. Checkout the following example that generates random values and checks your requirements in real-time.

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function randomBoolean(){
    return Math.random() < 0.5;
}


const choices = [];
const VAL      = 12;
const MAX_COST = 19;

for(let i = 0; i < 3000; i++){
    choices.push([
    {
        cost: getRandomInt(10), 
        val:  randomBoolean() ? 4 : 0
    }, 
    {
        cost: getRandomInt(10), 
      val:  4
    }, 
    {
        cost:  getRandomInt(10), 
      val: 4
    }
  ]);
}

const validChoices = choices.filter(options => {
  const totalValue = options.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.val + acc, 0);
    const totalCost = options.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.cost + acc, 0);
  
  return totalValue === VAL && totalCost <= MAX_COST; 
});

console.log(`found ${validChoices.length} valid choices`)
```